# Is there a way to toString a getter or setter function?

Tags: javascript

If we run the following code:

```js
const a = () => 1 + 2 + 3
console.log(a.toString())
```

...we should get:

```
() => 1 + 2 + 3
```

This works for normal functions but what if we want to do toString() for getter and setter functions to see the code? This [example](https://codepen.io/geoyws/pen/LYbmYab?editors=1111) shows that it wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you please add your example into the question instead of linking to it? (You can put it in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so it can be executed here as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access the property using dot notation, you'll invoke the getter. To *examine* the getter, examine the property on the object or prototype instead with `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`:

```js
const obj = {
  get a() {
    return 1 + 2 + 3;
  }
};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'a').get);
```

```js
class C {
  get a() {
    return 1 + 2 + 3;
  }
};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(C.prototype, 'a').get);
```